Different front end deployment for different customers using Ionic+React
I am developing a hybrid mobile application using Ionic+React and Capacitor. I will also use AppFlow to provide users with dynamic updates.
However, the nature of the application is a little different. Different clients might ask for some customizations in the forms or pages or business logic. We will have to edit the code as per their requirements.
The challenge is how will I achieve this? Is there a way that I can redirect users with specific company credentials to a separate background build of my app assuming ionic apps just render a webview? Can someone please help me with the approach here? I am still quite new to the Ionic+Capacitor+AppFlow tech stack.

Haven't used ionic, but can't you use code splitting? Single build with dynamic imports?

The problem is that as customers grow in number, I’ll be dealing with a heavy build with files specific to different customers sitting in a single build

But they won't be imported if not requested. You can lazy load only what you need to use https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy

So those files won't be a part of the main build?
